# Extract all url from sitemap.xml with PHP CURL

Tags: php, loops, curl, sitemap

I want to extract all url from sitemap.xml with PHP and CURL. My code work with content sitemap (e.g: http://www.phanmemtoday.com/sitemap.xml?page=1) but does not work with sitemap index (e.g: http://www.phanmemtoday.com/sitemap.xml).
Please help me. Thank you!

```
<?php
$sUrl="http://domain.com/sitemap.xml";

$aXmlLinks = array($sUrl);
$aOtherLinks = array();
while (!empty($aXmlLinks)) {
    foreach ($aXmlLinks as $i =>$sTmpUrl){
        unset($aXmlLinks[$i]);
        $aTmp = getlinkfromxmlsitemap($sTmpUrl);
        echo "Array temp link:<br>";
        print_r($aTmp);
        foreach ($aTmp as $sTmpUrl2) {
            if (strpos($sTmpUrl2, '.xml') !== false) {
                array_push($aXmlLinks,$sTmpUrl2);
            } else {
                array_push($aOtherLinks,$sTmpUrl2);
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<br>Array xml link:<br>";
    print_r($aXmlLinks);
    echo "<br>Array product link:<br>";
    print_r($aOtherLinks);
    echo "<br>-----------------------------------------<br>";
}
print_r($aOtherLinks);


function getlinkfromxmlsitemap($sUrl) {
    // echo "Get link from: $sUrl<br>";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sUrl);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $links = array();
    $count = preg_match_all('@<loc>(.+?)<\/loc>@', $data, $matches);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
        $links[] = $matches[0][$i];
    }
    return $links;  
}
?>
```

Comment: sitemap.xml has few child-sitemap link. I want to catch all child-sitemap link then extract all page link from them

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well, but you can improve some things please check the following example thar will return a nested array with the links your looking:

```
<?php
$sUrl1="http://www.phanmemtoday.com/sitemap.xml?page=1";
$sUrl2="http://www.phanmemtoday.com/sitemap.xml";

$aXmlLinks = array($sUrl1,$sUrl2);
$aOtherLinks = array();
while (!empty($aXmlLinks)) {
    foreach ($aXmlLinks as $i =>$sTmpUrl){
        unset($aXmlLinks[$i]);
        $aTmp = getlinkfromxmlsitemap($sTmpUrl);        
        array_push($aOtherLinks,$aTmp);        
    }
    echo "<br>Array xml link:<br>";
    print_r($aXmlLinks);
    echo "<br>Array product link:<br>";
    print_r($aOtherLinks);
    echo "<br>-----------------------------------------<br>";
}
print_r($aOtherLinks);


function getlinkfromxmlsitemap($sUrl) {
    // echo "Get link from: $sUrl<br>";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sUrl);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $error= curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $links = array();
    $count = preg_match_all('@<loc>(.+?)<\/loc>@', $data, $matches);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
        $links[] = $matches[0][$i];
    }
    return $links;  
}
?>
```

Comment: It not working well. I want to write a script to catch all child-sitemap from sitemap index, then catch all other link from child-sitemap.